# Scala Spark rdd combination in a file to match pairs

Tags: scala, apache-spark, combinations, rdd

I am learning Spark+Scala and I am stuck with this problem. I have two things. One file that contains many words (I show you for example the 2 first lines) :

```
scala> val text = sc.textFile("hdfs://master:9000/data/words.txt")
text: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = hdfs://master:9000/data/words.txt MapPartitionsRDD[1] at textFile at <console>:24

scala> text.take(2)
res0: Array[String] = Array("a b c d ", "e r t y u i o p ")
```

And I have a "combinations" variable representing pairs of frequent words (I show you for example the 2 first line) :

```
scala> val combinations = l.cartesian(l).filter{case(x,y) => x < y}
combinations: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, String)] = MapPartitionsRDD[9] at filter at <console>:32

scala> combinations.take(2)
res1: Array[(String, String)] = Array((a,b), (a,c))
```

I would like to creat combination pairs from each row of the "text" varable, in order to match them with "combinations" variable pairs.

for example, with the first row of the input text, I would like to have :

```
(a,b) (a,c) (a,d) (b,c) (b,d) (c,d)
```

so that I can match them with "combinations" variable

Please help! This is driving me crazy. Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood correctly, we would like to get combinations of the letters contained in each entry of `text`. For example:

```
"a b c d " => (a,b) (a,c) (a,d) (b,c) (b,d) (c,d)
```

We can do this using the Scala collections API:

```
val textCombinations = text.map(t => t.split(" ").combinations(2).toList)
```

Comment: scala> textCombinations.take(10).foreach(println)
16/12/17 11:45:42 ERROR executor.Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 5.0 (TID 5)
java.io.NotSerializableException: scala.collection.SeqLike$CombinationsItr
Serialization stack: ...

Comment: @Bebec I see. Make it `.combinations(2).toList` instead of `.toSeq`. Looks like the `toSeq` implementation defaults to a `Stream` which is not serializable. I updated the answer as well.